# Deploying Entity Framework 5 in production without using Nuget

Tags: deployment, frameworks, entity

Using the Nuget package I downloaded and used Entity framework. I created a class library use the Entity framework and another windows forms application that uses the library to create data.

While deploying to production, I used with Windows Forms Application bin content but EntityFramework.dll is not part of it.

**My question is :**

How to deploy/install the Entity framework into production without using Visual studio/Nuget package?

Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Entity Framwork reference to Copy Local = True, it should deploy into your bin folder when you build the project

[image]